# this.x is not iterable

Tags: javascript, debugging, iterator

I am trying to pass a variable to a method in an object and I keep getting an error that says *this.phrase is not iterable*

I am using two objects and passing that variable from one Object to the other

**Phrase Class**

```js
console.clear()
class Phrase {
  constructor(phrase) {
  console.log("Phrase constructor")
    this.phrase = phrase;
  }

  addPhraseToDisplay() {
  console.log("Phrase addPhraseToDisplay")
    let arr = [...this.phrase];
    arr.forEach(letter => {
      let li = $(`<li>${letter}</li>`);
      if (letter !== ' ') {
        li.addClass(`hide letter ${letter}`);
        $('#phrase ul').append(li);
      } else {
        let li = $(`<li>${letter}</li>`);
        li.addClass('hide space');
        $('#phrase ul').append(li);
      }
      return letter;
    });
  }

}


class Game {

  constructor() {
  console.log("Game constructor")
    this.missed = 0;
    //directly put the phrases in the constructor
    this.phrases = [new Phrase("hello world"),
      new Phrase("Wolf on wall street"),
      new Phrase("Despite making"),
      new Phrase("Karen took the kids"),
      new Phrase("alright about to head out")
    ];
    this.activePhrase = null;
  }

  getRandomPhrase() {
  console.log("Game getRandomPhrase()")
    //returns 5 of the random phrases
    return this.phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.phrases.length)];
  }


  startGame() {
  console.log("Game startGame")
    let hid = document.getElementById('overlay');
    hid.style.display = "none";
    let phrs = this.getRandomPhrase();
    let stor = new Phrase(phrs);
    stor.addPhraseToDisplay();
  }


}

g = new Game()
g.startGame()
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you call the classes?

Comment: Presumably this is because `phrs` in `startGame` is an object, which you then try to spread with `[...this.phrase]`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was that you created a new Phrase out of a phrase with this

```
let stor = new Phrase(phrs);
```

get rid of this and it works

```js
console.clear()
class Phrase {
  constructor(phrase) {
  console.log("Phrase constructor")
    this.phrase = phrase;
  }

  addPhraseToDisplay() {
  console.log("Phrase addPhraseToDisplay")
    let arr = [...this.phrase];
    arr.forEach(letter => {
      let li = $(`<li>${letter}</li>`);
      if (letter !== ' ') {
        li.addClass(`hide letter ${letter}`);
        $('#phrase ul').append(li);
      } else {
        let li = $(`<li>${letter}</li>`);
        li.addClass('hide space');
        $('#phrase ul').append(li);
      }
      return letter;
    });
  }

}


class Game {

  constructor() {
  console.log("Game constructor")
    this.missed = 0;
    //directly put the phrases in the constructor
    this.phrases = [new Phrase("hello world"),
      new Phrase("Wolf on wall street"),
      new Phrase("Despite making"),
      new Phrase("Karen took the kids"),
      new Phrase("alright about to head out")
    ];
    this.activePhrase = null;
  }

  getRandomPhrase() {
  console.log("Game getRandomPhrase()")
    //returns 5 of the random phrases
    return this.phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.phrases.length)];
  }


  startGame() {
  console.log("Game startGame")
    let hid = document.getElementById('overlay');
    hid.style.display = "none";
    let phrs = this.getRandomPhrase();
    //let stor = new Phrase(phrs);
    phrs.addPhraseToDisplay();
  }


}

g = new Game()
g.startGame()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="phrase"><ul></ul></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

This should do it

`addPhraseToDisplay` should be a method of `Game`and not of `Phrase`

```js
console.clear()
class Phrase {
  constructor(phrase) {
    this.phrase = phrase;
  }


}


class Game {

  constructor() {
    this.missed = 0;
    //directly put the phrases in the constructor
    this.phrases = [new Phrase("hello world"),
      new Phrase("Wolf on wall street"),
      new Phrase("Despite making"),
      new Phrase("Karen took the kids"),
      new Phrase("alright about to head out")
    ];
    this.activePhrase = null;
  }

  getRandomPhrase() {
    //returns 5 of the random phrases
    return this.phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.phrases.length)];
  }


  startGame() {
    let hid = document.getElementById('overlay');
    hid.style.display = "none";
    let phrs = this.getRandomPhrase();
    this.addPhraseToDisplay(phrs);
  }


  addPhraseToDisplay(phrs) {
    let arr = [...phrs.phrase];
    arr.forEach(letter => {
      let li = $(`<li>${letter}</li>`);
      if (letter !== ' ') {
        li.addClass(`hide letter ${letter}`);
        $('#phrase ul').append(li);
      } else {
        let li = $(`<li>${letter}</li>`);
        li.addClass('hide space');
        $('#phrase ul').append(li);
      }
      return letter;
    });
  }


}

g = new Game()
g.startGame()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="phrase"><ul></ul></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could've solved it. You were getting the error because of these lines:

```
let phrs = this.getRandomPhrase(); // phrs is an instance of Phrase
let stor = new Phrase(phrs); // stor is new Phrase(new Phrase(...))
stor.addPhraseToDisplay();
```

The way your code has it, `phrs` is already an instance of `Phrase`. Therefore, you declared `stor` as `new Phrase(new Phrase(/* some string */))`. The error results from `stor.addPhraseToDisplay` using spread syntax on the input to the `Phrase` constructor. This works fine when the input is a `String`, but you're using spread syntax on an instance of `Phrase`, which is not iterable; e.g., `[...new Phrase('abc')]`.

Simply remove `Phrase` constructor calls from `this.phrases` and instead implement it as an array of strings; then the error is no longer triggered:

```js
console.clear()
class Phrase {
  constructor(phrase) {
  console.log("Phrase constructor")
    this.phrase = phrase;
  }

  addPhraseToDisplay() {
  console.log("Phrase addPhraseToDisplay")
    let arr = [...this.phrase];
    arr.forEach(letter => {
      let li = $(`<li>${letter}</li>`);
      if (letter !== ' ') {
        li.addClass(`hide letter ${letter}`);
        $('#phrase ul').append(li);
      } else {
        let li = $(`<li>${letter}</li>`);
        li.addClass('hide space');
        $('#phrase ul').append(li);
      }
      return letter;
    });
  }

}


class Game {

  constructor() {
  console.log("Game constructor")
    this.missed = 0;
    //directly put the phrases in the constructor
    this.phrases = [
      "hello world",
      "Wolf on wall street",
      "Despite making",
      "Karen took the kids",
      "alright about to head out"
    ];
    this.activePhrase = null;
  }

  getRandomPhrase() {
  console.log("Game getRandomPhrase()")
    //returns 5 of the random phrases
    return this.phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.phrases.length)];
  }


  startGame() {
  console.log("Game startGame")
    let hid = document.getElementById('overlay');
    hid.style.display = "none";
    let phrs = this.getRandomPhrase();
    let stor = new Phrase(phrs);
    stor.addPhraseToDisplay();
  }


}

g = new Game()
g.startGame()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="phrase"><ul></ul></div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```